# python pytest occasionally fails with OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

While running a particular `unittest` with `pytest`, it occasionally fails with this error (mentioned in the title) and from the stack trace it happens on the line

`choice = input().lower()`

when the control reaches this statement, the entire function is:

```
def prompt_to_activate(bear, printer):
    PROMPT_TO_ACTIVATE_STR = ('program has found {} to be useful '
                              'based of dependencies discovered from your '
                              'project files. \n Would you like to activate '
                              'it? (y/n)')
    printer.print(PROMPT_TO_ACTIVATE_STR)

    choice = input().lower()

    if choice.startswith('y'):
        return True
    elif choice.startswith('n'):
        return False
    else:
        return prompt_to_activate(bear, printer)
for i in range(0, 3):
    a = i
print(a)
```

I tried adding some `time.sleep(x)` before that statement but that wouldn't fix it. Can somebody tell me the exact reason why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is an interactive function, you'll want to mock out the return value in your automated tests. Something like this:

```
def test_prompt(capsys, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('path.to.yourmodule.input', lambda prompt="", /: "no")
    val = prompt_to_activate(bear=..., printer=...)
    assert not val
```

Answer (score 14):

You might also receive this if you set a breakpoint, but didn't use the `-s` flag with pytest.

Comment: this was the solution for my issue

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else stumbles upon this, this error will also be raised if you forgot a pdb breakpoint (`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`) in your code.

Comment: If you want to use `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in your code, don't forget to add the `-s` flag with pytest, otherwise you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and figured it out after learning more unit testing and mocking! Adding to @wim's answer... Another way to mock input is:

```
@mock.patch("my_module.input")
def test_my_actual_func(self, mock_input):
    my_actual_func()
```